# Pickling decorated callable class wrapper

Tags: python, pickle, python-decorators

I'm struggling to pickle a wrapped function when I use a custom callable class as a wrapper.

I have a callable class "Dependee" that keeps track of dependencies for a wrapped function with a member variable "depends_on".  I'd like to use a decorator to wrap functions and also be able to pickle the resulting wrapped function.

So I define my dependee class.  Note the use of functools.update_wrapper.

```
>>> class Dependee:
...     
...     def __init__(self, func, depends_on=None):
...         self.func = func
...         self.depends_on = depends_on or []
...         functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
...         
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

Then I define my decorator such that it will return an instance of the Dependee wrapper class.

```
>>> class depends:
...     
...     def __init__(self, on=None):
...         self.depends_on = on or []
...     
...     def __call__(self, func):
...         return Dependee(func, self.depends_on)
...
```

Here's an example of a wrapped function.

```
>>> @depends(on=["foo", "bar"])
... def sum(x, y): return x+y
...
```

The member variable seems to be accessible.

```
>>> print(sum.depends_on)
['foo', 'bar']
```

I can call the function as expected.

```
>>> print(sum(1,2))
3
```

But I can't pickle the wrapped instance.

```
>>> print(pickle.dumps(sum))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function sum at 0x7f543863fbf8>: it's not the same object as __main__.sum
```

What am I missing?  How can I give pickle a more appropriately qualified name so that it can find the instance rather than the original function.  Note that manual wrapping works just fine.

```
>>> def sum2_func(x,y): return x+y
... 
>>> sum2 = Dependee(sum2_func, depends_on=["foo", "bar"])
>>> print(sum2.depends_on)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> print(sum2(1,2))
3
>>> print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(sum2)).depends_on)
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, well-known `pickle` problem -- can't pickle functions or classes that can't just be retrieved by their name in the module.  See e.g https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IssuesWithPickleModule for clear examples (specifically on how this affects `modwsgi`, but also of the issue in general).

In this case since all you're doing is adding attributes to the function, you can get away with a simplified approach:

```
class depends:

def __init__(self, on=None):
    self.depends_on = on or []

def __call__(self, func):
    func.func = func
    func.depends_on = self.depends_on or []
    return func
```

the `return func` is the key idea -- return the **same** object that's being decorated (possibly after decorating it, as here, with additional attributes -- but, **not** a different object, else the name-vs-identity issue perks up).

Now this will work (just your original code, only changing `depends` as above):

```
$ python d.py 
['foo', 'bar']
3
c__main__
sum
p0
.
```

Of course, this isn't a general-purpose solution (it only works if it's feasible for the decorator to return the same object it's decorating), just one that works in your example.

I am not aware of any serialization approach able to serialize and de-serialize Python objects without this limitation, alas.

Comment: That's too bad.  I was really hoping there was something I wasn't thinking of.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: There are at least two serialization packages that enable you to get around this limitation, and in a very straightforward manner.  See my answer for your code demonstrated with `dill`.  However, there is also `cloudpickle` if you for whatever reason don't want to use `dill`.

Answer (score 9):

You just need a better serializer, like `dill`.  As for how it works, `dill` just does a lot of registering python types with the equivalent of `copy_reg` -- it also treats `__main__` similarly to a module, and lastly can serialize by reference or by object.  So the last bit is relevant if you want to serialize a function or class, and take the class/function definition with the pickle.  It's a little bigger of a pickle than serializing by reference, but it's more robust.

Here's your code exactly:

```
>>> import dill
>>> import functors
>>> class Dependee:
...   def __init__(self, func, depends_on=None):
...     self.func = func
...     self.depends_on = depends_on or []
...     functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
...   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...     return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>>       
>>> class depends:
...   def __init__(self, on=None):
...     self.depends_on = on or []
...   def __call__(self, func):
...     return Dependee(func, self.depends_on)
... 
>>> @depends(on=['foo','bar'])
... def sum(x,y): return x+y
... 
>>> print(sum.depends_on)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> print(sum(1,2))
3
>>> _sum = dill.dumps(sum)
>>> sum_ = dill.loads(_sum)
>>> print(sum_(1,2))
3
>>> print(sum_.depends_on)
['foo', 'bar']
>>>
```

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation