# how to pickle class dynamically created from decorator in python 3.6

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.6

### Disclaimer:

Before reading this post know that I am trying to do something that is unconventional in python. Since "Don't do x" is not an answer to "how do I do x?" let's assume there is a very good reason to do this, even though in most cases it would not be good practice.

### The Question

Given I have a class that is dynamically created by applying a decorator to a function, how would I go about pickling an instance of said class?

For example, to set this up it might look like this:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps 


class BaseClass:
    pass


def _make_method(func):
    """ decorator for adding self as first argument to function """

    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    # set signature to include self
    sig = inspect.signature(decorator)
    par = inspect.Parameter('self', 1)
    new_params = tuple([par] + list(sig.parameters.values()))
    new_sig = sig.replace(parameters=new_params,
                          return_annotation=sig.return_annotation)
    decorator.__signature__ = new_sig
    return decorator


def snake2camel(snake_str):
    """ convert a snake_string to a CamelString """
    return "".join(x.title() for x in snake_str.split('_'))


def make_class(func):
    """ dynamically create a class setting the call method to function """
    name = snake2camel(func.__name__)  # get the name of the new class
    method = _make_method(func)
    cls = type(name, (BaseClass,), {'__call__': method}) 
    return cls()


@make_class
def something(arg):
    return arg
```

Now something is an instance of the dynamically created class `Something`.

```
type(something)  # -> __main__.Something
isinstance(something, BaseClass)  # -> True
```

which works fine, but when I try to pickle it (or use the multiprocessing module which uses pickle under the hood):

```
import pickle
pickle.dumps(something)  # -> raises
```

it throws this error:

```
# PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Something'>: attribute lookup Something on __main__ failed
```

So I thought I could redefine `BaseClass` to use a **reduce** method like so:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __reduce__(self):
        return make_class, (self.__call__.__func__,)
```

but then it throws the dreaded "not the same object" error:

```
# PicklingError: Can't pickle <function something at 0x7fe124cb2d08>: it's not the same object as __main__.something
```

How can I make this work without bringing in dependencies? I need to be able to pickle the `something` object so I can use it with the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class from the concurrent.futures module in python 3.6, so simply using dill or cloudpickle is probably not an option here.

Comment: I suspect it's not possible. Pickle stores classes by name, so if the name doesn't refer to the original class in your namespace, you can't pickle it.

Comment: Here is a similar question I was not able to find before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641859/pickling-decorated-callable-class-wrapper. It appears it isn't possible. I either have to use dill or cloudpickle, or abandon the class and just attach attributes to the original function.